# Confused with json object and string and JSON.parse and JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, string

I'm using node.js to handle ajax request and return a object back.

If I use `res.json(obj);`, then I get a `string`, and I can use `JSON.parse(string)` to convert it to object, everything is fine.

But if I use `res.json(JSON.stringify(obj))`, I can also get a `string`, but the `JSON.parse(string)` won't convert it to object.

What's the difference between the two `string`? Their content look the same. I was using the `typeof()` to check them.

Comment: **JSON.stringify** is used to convert an object into string.

**JSON.parse** is used to convert object represented as string into object. eg: `var obj = { prop1: "first", prop2: "Second"}`.

But is string passed in JSON.parse, it will throw error. The catch is, the string passed to JSON.parse should be a proper formatted object

Comment: So you mean `JSON.parse` is expecting an object? But I use `typeof()` to check the data, it's definitely `string`. How can I distinguish the "object represented as string" and a real "string"?

Comment: No. It expects string. Kindly refer to [MDN - JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Answer (score 0):

So [`res.json`](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/response.js) makes use of JSON.stringify (see line 242) but it does make its own edits by specifying its own `json replacer` and `json spaces`.

These are both things [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) can take in to alter how it stringifies the JSON. After looking deeper, it seems like `json spaces` and `json replacer` aren't set by default so Express simply makes it so that if they are set in your apps settings, it will pull them and make sure your JSON responses match up correctly.

It also does some things like setting the Content type, etc.